# How is a class literal compiled to Java bytecode?

Tags: java, bytecode

```
public class A {
}

public class B {
    public static void b() {
        System.out.println(A.class);
    }
}
```

How is the class literal `A.class` compiled in B.class's bytecode? Is it a field reference? I can't find a mention of that in the bytecode documentation from Oracle/Sun.

Decompilers have no trouble reconstructing it, whatever it is:

```
java -jar decompiler.jar B.class
```

Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: '-Dfile.encoding=UTF8'

1. //
       // Decompiled by Procyon v0.5.30
       //

   ```
   public class B
   {
       public static void b() {
           System.out.println(A.class); <<<
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: You marked it as an exact duplicate yet in the answers there is no mention of bytecode. My question concerns bytecode. Is the object representing the class a constant field, a variable field, a constant field ref, a variable field ref, or something else? If it's a ref to a field, what class has that field? Class.class doesn't, obviously, so it has to be the class A in my example. So what is it in A? A variable? A static constant?

Comment: Not sure about bytecode, but if it's any help - reference to the class object is held by the classloader that loaded that class, so you could call it a (part of) variable field of the classloader.

Comment: I can't post an answer, as this was marked as a duplicate (and I can't un-mark it, apparently).  The `.class` operator compiles to a 'load constant' instruction (`ldc` or `ldc_w`), where the operand is an index into the constant pool.  The constant pool entry is a `Class_info` structure (not `Fieldref_info`).  That structure simply points to yet another entry: a `Utf8` entry containing the type descriptor (type name in the form `package/name/ClassName`).  You can verify this yourself by compiling a simple example and running it through `javap -v`.

Comment: Thank you, that's very useful! Not sure why stackoverflow is being so doctrinaire about this question, which definitely doesn't duplicate the alleged duplicate.

Answer (score 11):

Before Java 5, a class literal like `A.class` was just syntactic sugar for calling `Class.forName("A")` under the hood, translating a `ClassNotFoundException` to a `NoClassDefFoundError` and, depending on the compiler, cache the result in a synthetic `static` field of the containing class, i.e. `B`.

The reason is that class literals were introduced in Java 1.1 as a language feature, but the byte code was not changed to have special support for it.

Since Java 5, class literals are treated as real constants, being loaded to the operand stack using a single `ldc` or `ldc_w` instruction, just like with `String` literals. The difference lies in the type of the constant pool item, it refers to, [`String_info`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.4.3) for `String` constants and [`Class_info`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.4.1) for `Class` constants.

As a side note, since Java 7, the Java bytecode even allows to load constants of type [`MethodType`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/lang/invoke/MethodType.html) or [`MethodHandle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/lang/invoke/MethodHandle.html) which has no actual Java language equivalent.

See [`ldc`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.ldc):

> The *index* is an unsigned byte that must be a valid index into the run-time constant pool of the current class (§2.6). The run-time constant pool entry at *index* either must be a run-time constant of type `int` or `float`, or a reference to a string literal, or a symbolic reference to a class, method type, or method handle (§5.1).
>
> If the run-time constant pool entry is a run-time constant of type `int` or `float`, the numeric *value* of that run-time constant is pushed onto the operand stack as an `int` or `float`, respectively.
>
> Otherwise, if the run-time constant pool entry is a `reference` to an instance of class `String` representing a string literal (§5.1), then a `reference` to that instance, *value*, is pushed onto the operand stack.
>
> Otherwise, if the run-time constant pool entry is a symbolic reference to a class (§5.1), then the named class is resolved (§5.4.3.1) and a `reference` to the `Class` object representing that class, *value*, is pushed onto the operand stack.
>
> Otherwise, the run-time constant pool entry must be a symbolic reference to a method type or a method handle (§5.1). The method type or method handle is resolved (§5.4.3.5) and a `reference` to the resulting instance of `java.lang.invoke.MethodType` or `java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle`, value, is pushed onto the operand stack.

Since you mentioned decompilers, most decompilers are even capable of recognizing the more complex pre-Java 5 code patterns and decompile them to a class literal. Of course, the simple `ldc` instruction is trivial to decompile.

Comment: I suppose it's time Procyon joined "most decompilers" in handling the old-style patterns :).