# getMethod throws method not found exception

Tags: java, reflection

I am using the getMethod(String name, Class[] types) method to get a method but I get a method not found when there is an int parameter. I think I get that because inside my Class array I have the java.lang.Integer class (the wrapper) instead of int. I get that class by using a generic Object.getClass() so I don't think I can change that easily. Here is the part of the code that does this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < parameterTypes.length; i++) {
        parameterTypes[i] = arguments[i].getClass();
}

try {
    Method mmethod = mclass.getMethod(contractName, parameterTypes);
} catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {}
```

Can I solve this somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you have this class

```
class ReflectTest {
    Object o = null;
    public void setO(int i) {
        System.out.println("set int");
        o = i;
    }
    public void setO(Integer i) {
        System.out.println("set Integer");
        o = i;
    }
}
```

`setO(int i)` and `setO(Integer i)` are two different methods, so you cannot have only one of them in your class and rely on autoboxing to get the method object via `Class#getMethod(Class<?>...)` and passing one or the other argument type.

```
@Test
public void invoke() throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {
    Method method = ReflectTest.class.getMethod("setO", int.class);
    method.invoke(new ReflectTest(), 3);
    method.invoke(new ReflectTest(), Integer.valueOf(3));

    method = ReflectTest.class.getMethod("setO", Integer.class);
    method.invoke(new ReflectTest(), 3);
    method.invoke(new ReflectTest(), Integer.valueOf(3));
}
```

will both print

```
set int
set int
```

and

```
set Integer
set Integer
```

Here autoboxing works on invokation.

But in you case you extract the type of the argument from a value which is stored as `Object`. In this case primitive types are autoboxed into theire respective wrapper types, hence you do not find a method which corresponds to `int.class` as argument.

```
@Test
public void invoke() throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {
    invoke(new ReflectTest(), "setO", 3);
    invoke(new ReflectTest(), "setO", Integer.valueOf(3));
}

private void invoke(Object instance, String methodeName, Object argValue) throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {
    System.out.println(argValue.getClass().isPrimitive());
    Method method = ReflectTest.class.getMethod("setO", argValue.getClass());
    method.invoke(new ReflectTest(), argValue);
    method.invoke(new ReflectTest(), Integer.valueOf(3));
}
```

Here the output is:

```
false
set Integer
false
set Integer
```

As you see, no primitives and only the method with `Integer.class` is found and called. If you remove it you will get `NoSuchMethodException`.

So to solve your problem change the method your are trying to invoke via reflection to take a wrapper type or better yet, pass the correct argument types instead of deriving them from some values.

Finally, `NoSuchMethodException` is also thrown when the method is not accessible i.e. not `public`, make sure the method is public.

Answer (score 0):

As per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3925587/java-reflection-calling-constructor-with-primitive-types), you should use `Integer.TYPE` to refer to the primitive `int` for reflection purposes.